# How To get Access Token Using HttpClient

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, httpclient, hubspot, hubspot-crm

I am integrating my application with Hubspot CRM. I need to get Access token using OAuth2.0. I Initiated the authorization and tried to get access token using HTTPClient . But I could not get Response. I have added my code below. What is the mistake i am doing , I use the same redirect uri when i used to initiate authorization.

Code

```
String grant_type = "authorization_code";

            HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://api.hubapi.com/oauth/v1/token");
            List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("code", code));
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", client_id));
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", client_secret));
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("redirect_uri", redirect_uri));
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", grant_type));
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));
            DefaultHttpClient httpClients = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpClients.execute(post);
```

**Response Error**

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
{"status":"BAD_AUTH_CODE","message":"missing or unknown auth code","correlationId":"e33b84e6-6a60-47c4-8f66-d2826fcada44","requestId":"e74fa273f7e927a21dd5a0676c0f0e61"}
```

Comment: I think this is not possible in this way. Create a form, submit post request to the HubSpot CRM url by specifying redirect URL in some hidden field or somewhere. And receive the response from the redirect_url .  Refer this url
https://integrate.hubspot.com/t/get-access-token-in-a-console-application-no-user-interface/1584/2